# python: how to avoid name clash when subclass has same name?

Tags: python, name-mangling

name mangling works most of the time but not when a subclass has the same name as a super class; for example if two classes in different modules `m2.A` extends `m1.A`, then `m2.A.foo` will hide `m1.A.foo` because both of them become `_A__foo`; is there an option to enable a "fuller" name mangling, namely, mangle class fields with a unique class identifier?

```
# m1.py
class C:
    def __foo(self):
        print('C1')

    def bar(self):
        self.__foo()

# main.py
from m1 import C as C1

class C(C1):
    # i mangle this for internal use within this class, not expecting it to
    # break a super class method; so i cant safely use a name even if it is
    # mangled; sad, is there a way to mangle with a guid across all classes?
    def __foo(self):
        print('CM')

C().bar()   # CM not C1
```

Comment: No. And honestly, you should just stick to having different names for subclasses. I've never seen this sort of thing before and it's a highly unusual use-case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is hard to guarantee your subclass name is different from *any* superclass, which could lie in a deeply chained library...

Answer (score 1):

The module name is designed to be a part of the namespace, I think the simplest answer of  'full name mangling' is just add the module name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't come up with a meaningful name in the subclass that is different from the superclass, that should be telling you one of 2 things:

- Something is not quite right with the design. Is your subclass really so similar to the superclass that you must name it the same (or: is the attribute in the subclass really that similar to something in the superclass)? If that is the case, does it even make sense to make a subclass (or to add it only in the subclass?)?
- Your names are not meaningful. Give things more descriptive names and this problem will go away.